# FileInputStream - could not find writer for content-type application/tar

Tags: java, rest, maven, jboss, fileinputstream

I'm trying to send a FileInputStream (tar file) to a rest-api client application.
I have included that client as a dependency in an application which is also included in another application.

Calling the method taking in the fileInputStream respectively passing it through as a parameter:

client app: works

app1 --> client app: works

app2 --> app1 --> client: this error:

> Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:442)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation$2.call(ClientInvocation.java:477)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: could not find writer for
>   content-type application/tar type: java.io.FileInputStream    at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.ClientWriterInterceptorContext.throwWriterNotFoundException(ClientWriterInterceptorContext.java:40)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.getWriter(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.proceed(AbstractWriterInterceptorContext.java:117)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.writeRequestBody(ClientInvocation.java:341)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.writeRequestBodyToOutputStream(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:558)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.buildEntity(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:524)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.loadHttpMethod(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:423)
>     at
>   org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:281)
>     ... 7 more

I'm not sure what's causing this...

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Ok I've "solved" the problem. There was a dependency which is using resteasy to implement a rest client and it's incompatible with the jersey dependencies used in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've "solved" the problem. There was a dependency which is using resteasy to implement a rest client and it's incompatible with the jersey dependencies used in the app.

Comment: Which was the dependency that was causing the issue?

Comment: If I remember correctly the issue was Jersey1, which is being used in Netflix's Eureka.